# http getJSON in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I downloaded the [News Feed with Images and Text Items](https://market.nativescript.org/) Nativescript app locally and am trying to make it work with a live feed from newsapi.org.

The original app has json hardcoded like so:

```
allNews: { source: Source, author: string, title: string, description: string, url: string, urlToImage: string, publishedAt: string }[] = [{ "source": { "id": null, "name": "Yahoo.com" }, "author": null, "title": "The Latest: Russia says no evidence of gas attack in Douma", "description": null, "url": "https://www.yahoo.com/news/latest-turkey-urges-sides-avoid-more-syria-turmoil-113652213.html", "urlToImage": null, "publishedAt": "2018-04-13T19:44:00Z" }, { "source": { "id": "the-washington-post", "name": "The Washington Post" }, "author": "http://www.facebook.com/matt.zapotosky", "title": "Trump issues pardon to 'Scooter' Libby, former chief of staff to Vice President Cheney", "description": "The Bush administration aide was convicted of perjury before a grand jury, lying to FBI investigators and obstruction of justice.", "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/trump-issues-pardon-to-scooter-libby-former-chief-of-staff-to-vice-president-cheney/2018/04/13/dfa4039a-3f2d-11e8-8d53-eba0ed2371cc_story.html", "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/rf/image_1484w/2010-2019/WashingtonPost/2018/04/13/National-Politics/Images/AFP_13Z4QQ.jpg?t=20170517", "publishedAt": "2018-04-13T19:06:25Z" }, { "source": { "id": "the-new-york-times", "name": "The New York Times" }, "author": "", "title": "Where's the Boom in Bank Lending?: DealBook Briefing", "description": "Bank lending was expected to surge this year. But going by bank results so far, lending in the first quarter is set to disappoint.", "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/13/business/dealbook/trump-trans-pacific-partnership.html", "urlToImage": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/02/03/us/14db-newsletter-wells/14db-newsletter-wells-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg", "publishedAt": "2018-04-13T18:56:00Z" }];
```

Inside my `app/home/home-view-model.ts` I added:

```
import { getJSON } from "tns-core-modules/http";
...

   allNews: { source: Source,
               author: string,
               title: string, 
               description: string, 
               url: string, 
               urlToImage: string, 
               publishedAt: string 
            }[] = getJSON("newsapi link").then((r: any) => {
            }, (e) => {
            });
             ;
```

I am doing this based on the documentation here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http. However, getting an error:

```
app/home/home-view-model.ts(20,5): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '{ source: Source; author: string; title: string; description: string; url: string; urlToImage: string; publishedAt: string; }[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Promise<void>'.
app/home/home-page.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'data/observable'.
app/home/home-page.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ui/layouts/stack-layout'.
app/home/home-view-model.ts(20,5): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '{ source: Source; author: string; title: string; description: string; url: string; urlToImage: string; publishedAt: string; }[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Promise<void>'.
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the result of the .then call, which is a Promise. Both the call to getJSON() and .then() return promises (to allow chaining).

Instead, you want to assign the value inside the resolve handler of the promise:

```
allNews: { source: Source,
           author: string,
           title: string, 
           description: string, 
           url: string, 
           urlToImage: string, 
           publishedAt: string 
        }[]; // just declare the variable here
 getJSON("newsapi link").then((r: any) => {
   allNews = r; // assign it from the response when successful
 }, (e) => {
 });
```

Here's a link with more information on Promises that might be helpful:
https://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/

Comment: The code above gives me a syntax error (vscode) at the `.then`, the error is `[ts] '{' or ';' expected. [1144]` The only way I can get vscode not to scream at me is with something like this: https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/63e47a09bfa84490803e859f086d04e8

Comment: How you store the data in the allNews variable is up to you. If it's class scoped you can use this.allNews. My point is that getJSON returns a promise and you need to use .then to handle its resolve and reject calls.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be sure and follow up with a complete solution here. I needed to assign the getJSON function to a variable to get this to work. Note the fooBar variable below:

```
 allNews: { source: Source,
        author: string,
        title: string, 
        description: string, 
        url: string, 
        urlToImage: string, 
        publishedAt: string 
     }[]; // just declare the variable here

    getData = getJSON("newsapi link").then((r: any) => {
    this.allNews = r; // assign it from the response when successful
    }, (e) => {
    });
```